# Override class type for the current project

Tags: typescript

Say I have a TS class that looks like this one:

```
// Class.ts

export type Foo = string

export class Bar {
    foo: Foo = ''

    constructor(foo: Foo) {
        this.foo = foo
    }

    logFoo() {
        console.log(this.foo)
    }
}
```

The type of `Foo` is a generic string, and rightfully so, because this class is meant to be very general, doesn't really care about which string is passed to the constructor and will have to work across different projects;

The problem is that in specific projects, `Foo` should actually be an union of specific string literals, i.e. it should look something like this:

```
export type Foo = 'stringA' | 'stringB' | 'stringC'
```

How do I go about changing `Foo`'s definition for a specific project without touching `class.ts`? I guess I should import another file overriding its definition in the "consuming" file? But if so, how should I do that exactly?

In other words, assuming `Foo` should actually be defined as the union of string literals above, for example, in this case:

```
// file1.ts

import { Bar } from './classes/Class'

const bar1 = new Bar('hello') // this should throw an error
const bar2 = new Bar('stringA') // this shouldn't throw an error
```

and in this case:

```
// file2.ts

import { Foo } from './classes/Class'

const obj1: { 'key': Foo } = {
    key: 'hello' // this should throw an error
}
const obj2: { 'key': Foo } = {
    key: 'stringA' // this shouldn't throw an error
}
```

Comment: Why isn't Bar just generic over Foo, so the default can be the current string but consumers can supply more specific types as needed?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean, I'm trying to get my head around TypeScript, so many concepts aren't fully engraved yet. I guess you mean making use of Generics to fix the problem somehow?

Comment: Yes, have a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, the problem here is that I'll have to treat variables of type `Foo` as strings within the class, and without somehow asserting that the generic type will be a subset of `string` the compiler will throw errors (e.g. on line 6 of the example I posted). I think it's trickier than it looks.

Comment: _Is_ that a problem? The generic type _will_ be a subset of string. Constraining the generic is also covered in those docs.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W4xo7W) work for you?  This is just using a generic type parameter as jonrsharpe recommended, properly [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `string` (unlike the answer by pigrammer).  If it works and you want me to write up an answer, reply to me via @jcalz and I'll do so.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're right, I went through the docs when you sent me the link, however it flew over my head that the section you're referring to was what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @jcalz That would work perfectly, thank you! If you want to post your answer since pigrammer's answer even though very helpful doesn't cover that requirement...

Comment: I see `extends string` in pigrammer's answer now, so I'm not sure what my answer would do differently, other than explain more.  What specifically about pigrammer's answer is not meeting your requirement?

Comment: @jcalz Yeah it now does, I hadn't noticed they updated their answer. So yeah, not really much left to add to it at this point, and no more uncovered requirements. But still, thanks a lot for taking the time to explain and write the fiddle. I appreciate it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generics:

```js
// Class.ts


export class Bar<Foo extends string = string> {
    foo: Foo = ''

    constructor(foo: Foo) {
        this.foo = foo
    }

    logFoo() {
        console.log(this.foo)
    }
}
```

So then, use it like:

```js
// ModifiedClass.ts
import { Bar as OriginalBar } from 'Class.ts'

type ThisFoo = 'stingA' | 'stringB' | 'stringC'

export type Bar = OriginalBar<ThisFoo>
```

Comment: Thanks, this won't allow me to treat variables of type `Foo` within the class as strings though (in fact the example itself will throw an error at line 4), as really `Foo` could be whatever (even a numeric type). Is there a way to specify that `Foo` will be a subset of `string`? Perhaps I should have made this clearer in the question.

Comment: @kos Just use `Foo extends string` to restrict it to `string` and subtypes.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up figuring it out myself, sorry but my typescript is noobish at best. Thank you!